# How can re-render a child component in a parent component in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I have an activation component that call a api to send a code to user's mobile in this case I have a timer that I want re-render the timer component after resend sms's button clicked but I can't , 
I want re-render  component after when Resend code button clicked

```
<div>
    <label className={myClasses.DRT_Label}>
        Please wait 
        <span style={{margin : '0 5px' , fontSize : '15px'}}>
            <CountDown seconds={60} />
        </span>
        seconds .
    </label>
</div>
<div className={classes.button}>
    <ButtonTemp
        type="span"
        mode="success"
        styles={{ width: '120px' }}
        invertcolor
        class="marginLeft"
        disabled={disable}
        onclick={(e) => resendSmsHandler(e)}
    >
        Resend code
    </ButtonTemp>
    <ButtonTemp
        type="span"
        mode="success"
        styles={{ width: '120px' }}
        disabled={!canClick}
        onclick={(e) => loginClickHandler(e)}
    >
            Login
    </ButtonTemp>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to keep yours `seconds` in state,

```
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(60)
```

And pass value from state,

```
<CountDown seconds={seconds} />
```

Now whenever you want to re-render the timer you just need to reset your state `seconds` to its initial value and your child component will get re-render.

```
const resendSmsHandler = () => {
   setSeconds(60)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help ; i tried this but not work i don't the reason

Comment: no everything is ok , i use last version of react that use useState instead of state

Comment: countdown is my custom component that show numbers counting down

Comment: post your countdown component